# Is it possible to add a second switch to a light, without unearthing the wires to the existing switch

Tags: wiring, multiway-switch

I have a hall light with the only switch by the front door. The light fixture is ~3 meter from the door.

At the foot of the hall stair, about 2 meters away from the door in the *other* direction, is an existing switch panel for the landing light.
I want to add an additional switch to that panel, which will be a 2nd switch for the hall light.

Question 1:

Assuming that I want the "normal" version of a 2-switch light (i.e. flipping either switch will change the light's state, irrespective of the other switch's position) ... **am I right in thinking this can't be achieved without digging out the all of the existing run from the front door to the light fixture.** (which is in the wall/ceiling)?

---

Question 2:

Suppose I were willing to put up with "both switches have to be in the 'on' position for the light to work" (i.e. either switch can turn the hall light *off* on it's own, but you'd sometimes have to flip *both* switches to turn the light *on*). **Now** can this be done without digging out the existing run?

---

Question 3:

On the assumption that Q1 is "Yes, you have to dig it out" and Q2 is "Yes, you can install that without going back to the front door switch".
**Would it be possible to install "Q2" in such a way that *in the future*, I can come back and convert to Q1, without having to redo this 2nd spur?**

i.e. can I "Do Q2 with the extra run setup up to support 2 switches, and then see how palatable that set up is. And if it's too annoying then come back and fix the existing run to properly support both switches, without having to *redo* the new run"

---

All of this has to be standard electrical wiring. WiFi or "smart" switches are (alas) completely out of the question.

Comment: Is it feasible to run surface trunking from the existing switch location to the proposed switch location?  That's going to be the main determinant right there...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I was considering surface trunking to be the same as digging the wire out of the wall - they're both things I want to avoid if possible.

Comment: How would you get the wire to the new switch?  Any new switches would require a neutral.

Comment: Ah, I've missed off a step. Apologies, will edit.

Comment: @JACK editted. The new switch at the foot of the stairs would be added to an existing switch panel (which currently controls the landing light).

Comment: Ah, which makes the conversations about "existing switches" confusing ... :(

Comment: I want to avoid trenching or surface-trunking to the **front-door switch** if at all possible. I'd be happy with having surface-trunking between the light and the **staircase switch**.

Comment: There are smart switches that can do this. The issue will be you have to purchase both quite expensive and they take full sized openings (larger box will be needed) I cannot remember if they made one without a neutral required but most balk at the price of ~70$ just for the electronic 3/4 way switch.  master snd slave required or controller and remote for those offended  by the first term.

Comment: @EdBeal I read the question and was about to write my answer when I saw your comment. Write it up as an answer and it is perfect, including the part about the neutral, which could be a real issue here.

Comment: Maybe it's just a language barrier from across the pond, but you don't sound like you should be doing this.

Comment: This question could use with a dose of additional details in the form of a drawing or picture. While the question in the dupe target is different, the answer is really the same, though the OP seems to know that and is looking for a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

There are smart switches that can do this. The issue will be you have to purchase both quite expensive and they take full sized openings (larger box will be needed at the stairwell single gang box) I cannot remember if they made one without a neutral required but most balk at the price of ~70$ just for the electronic 3/4 way switch. master snd slave required or controller and remote for those offended by the first term. I believe the series is caseta  by lutron the current price 60$  Theee were others that did not require hubs same MFG that I have used.
You need to verify if a neutral is available or needed by the switch some require neutral some require ground to operate.

Comment: by 'Smart' I assume that you mean "WiFi/Bluetooth communcating"? If so, those are (alas) forbidden on non-debatable grounds.

Comment: There are many kinds some use a signal over the feeder some use RF there are many different types, the more restrictions you impose the higher the cost will be as most don’t want to pay 70$ for a switch that requires another of a similar type to do 3 way and yet another to do a 4 way. At this point it becomes cheaper to open walls and pull in a new cable when diy. I did not see the additional “questions” and the site format limits the questions, not all smart switches require WiFi some communicate over the existing wiring that powers the switch.

Comment: @Brondahl -- there are a few options aside from WiFi, Bluetooth, and other such 2.4GHz protocols. The Lutron gear runs on a proprietary radio protocol at lower radio frequencies (similar to what garage door opener remotes use), and Insteon uses a mix of RF and powerline signaling